# When i change screen resolution my whole website falls apart, what can i do?

Tags: html, css, alignment, background-image, margin

Whenever i use an older macbook or computer my website falls apart, the margins and the background-image just is trash. I know that the problem lays with my background-image but i really want to keep those elements and i dont see another way of putting these in. I cant find a way to put them in with CSS.

Ive already tried seperating the background images and other elements and adding them in via css but that is out of my league.

```
.index-background{
    background-image: url("../assets/img/index-background-3.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 425rem;
    width: 192rem;
}
```

I want my website to look good on any resolution

Comment: We can't possibly solve your problem from a single CSS rule. Look into media queries and read up on some tutorials. I also have absolutely no idea what _"Ive already tried seperating the toiletpaper"_ means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@media is going to be your friend here. With this you can target different resolutions.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) {
.index-background{ height: HEIGHTTHATWORKS FOR THESE RANGES;
width: WIDTHTHATWORKS; }}
```

The above will change the height and width of index-background if the browser width is equal to or between 768px and 1024px.

You can also check this out... https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp.
It will show you the different ways you can change the background to fill the area the way you need it to be filled.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it!